# Use VBA to enable a text box when a check box is checked

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am new to VBA and I'm trying to create a form in Access where a text box is enabled or disabled based on whether a check box is checked or unchecked.

So if the 'Survey Requested?' box is checked the 'Date Survey Requested' box is enabled for the user to enter a date.

I have the following code:

```
  Private Sub CheckSurveyRequested_AfterUpdate()

If CheckSurveyRequested = True Then
    DateSurveyReq.Enabled = True
Else
    DateSurveyReq.Enabled = False
End If

End Sub
```

But this comes up with a '424 Object Required' error when I run line 5.

Anyone have a suggestion as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Remove the `Set` keyword. Just `DateSurveyReq.Enabled = False`.

Comment: Tip: `DateSurveyReq.Enabled = CheckSurveyRequested.Value` is a nice one-liner to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry the `Set` is a typo, I've taken it out but still getting the same error

Comment: Could you please clarify how I can use `DateSurveyReq.Enabled = CheckSurveyRequested.Value` instead? that doesn't seem to be working for me either

Comment: Line 5 is `Else`. Which line do you mean?

Comment: Use `Me.DateSurveyReq.Enabled = Me.CheckSurveyRequested.Value` for form controls. Make sure you have [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) in place.

Comment: By Line 5 I mean `DateSurveyReq.Enabled = False` . I've tried adding `Me` but i get a compile error 'invalid use of Me keyword'

Comment: Then there are strange things going on in your code, and more errors are probably waiting for you. If `DateSurveyReq` is a control on the same form as `CheckSurveyRequested`, `Me.` must work for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely use the `AfterUpdate` event---tying the behavior of your textbox to the click event means that a user using their keyboard to navigate the form won't get the same behavior.

Also, you should replicate this behavior when the form loads: If the default value for the checkbox is `False`, then your textbox should be disabled when the form loads.

Also, as @ErikA notes, you can do this with one readable line.

So I would recommend something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub chkSurveyRequested_AfterUpdate()
    Me.txtDateSurveyReq.Enabled = Me.chkSurveyRequested.value
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.txtDateSurveyReq.Enabled = Me.chkSurveyRequested.value
End Sub
```

In order to not repeat yourself, you could move this code into a separate sub:

Option Explicit

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    ' assign the function below to the AfterUpdate event of the checkbox.
    Me.chkSurveyRequested.AfterUpdate = "=UpdateControls()"

    ' now execute the function directly
    UpdateControls
End Sub

Private Function UpdateControls()
    Me.txtDateSurveyReq.Enabled = Me.chkSurveyRequested.value
End Function
```

Comment: In your last example, shouldn't the function be assigned to the AfterUpdate event as part of the **Load** event for the form?

Comment: @LeeMac: you're right. I'll update when I'm back in front of a computer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following -

```
Private Sub CheckSurveyRequested_AfterUpdate()
    DateSurveyReq.Enabled = CheckSurveyRequested
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried this but unfortunately the same '424 Object Required' error is occurring

Comment: @Alex This error must occur elsewhere in your code, since the above is valid VBA.